# Calling a method from within an if/if else statement

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, call

Is it possible to call a method within an if statement, and then a separate method in an if else statement?

I have created a scanner than reads keyboard input, and based on the option the user gives, a different method will be called. Can I say something along the lines of:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
char choice = in.next().charAt(0);

if(choice == 1)
{
    private static void doAddStudent(Student aStudent) 
    {
        this.theRegistry.addStudent(aStudent);
    }
}
```

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: yes it is very much possible . very much legal :)

Comment: there's an important difference between defining a method (`private void methodName(Object parameter)`) and invoking (or calling) a method; you've written this as a definition where you want an invocation.

Comment: it is possible but it is also wrong. Methods should be declared out of any logic. You should invoke them from the if statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can of course call a method within an if or else block. But what you tried in your snippet is DECLARING a method within a block which is impossible.

fixed snippet:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
char choice = in.next().charAt(0);

if(choice == 1)
{
    this.theRegistry.addStudent(aStudent);
}
```

**EDIT:**

I think the code you want looks something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //some code
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    char choice = in.next().charAt(0);

    if(choice == 1)
    {
        RegistryInterface.doAddStdent(student);
    }
    //some code
}
```

The RegistryInterface.java

```
public class RegistryInterface {
    private static void doAddStudent(Student aStudent) {
        this.theRegistry.addStudent(aStudent);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean, but where would I declare the method? Outside of the if statement?

Comment: within a class. if you are working with the main method: outside of the main methode

Comment: I'm not working with the main method yet, just within my RegistryInterface class. Can i declare and call the method within the RegistryInterface class, or do i have to call it from within the main method? Thanks for your help

Comment: You can create your method in any class you want , and call it in any class you want ,  Try this link to know [How to create the Method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm)

Comment: we have been instructed for this assignment to put the main method in a different file; RegistryApp. RegistryInterface is just where we are declaring our methods.

Comment: i updated my answer once again. i hope that helps. coudl you please update your question with more code and in which files the code is?

Comment: @PhilippSander: i think that you need to create an object from `RegistryInterface ` when you call it , Like : `RegistryInterface  r = new RegistryInterface (); r.doAddStdent(student);` ????

Comment: not if the method is static in the RegistryInterface class. but it is possible that assignment tells him to do so ;-) but i cant know that ;-) then your code would be right

Comment: aha ,  i got it , sorry :)

Comment: One more thing sorry, i have used the code you gave me, and i am getting one error in the RegistryApp, it cannot find the symbol aStudent within the line RegistryInterface.doAddStdent(student);

Comment: you have to declare the student first.
Student student = new Student();

Answer (score 2):

Well you can.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
char choice = in.next().charAt(0);

if(choice == 1)
    this.theRegistry.addStudent(aStudent);
else if choice == 2)
    this.theRegistry.removeStudent(aStudent);
else
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid choice.");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes , create your method first , and then call them inside the `if` statement , Like this:

```
private static void doAddStudent(Student aStudent) 
        {
            this.theRegistry.addStudent(aStudent);
        }
```

then

```
 if(choice == 1)
    {
        doAddStudent(aStudent) ;////here you call the doAddStudent method

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you're not just calling a method inside the `if` statement - you're trying to define a new method. And this is illegal.

I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
char choice = in.next().charAt(0);
if(choice == '1') {
    this.theRegistry.addStudent(aStudent);
}
```

Also note that you were comparing `char choise` against an int `1`. I suppose you want to compare against char `'1'`

Answer (score 1):

Calling  method  is static

```
static TheRegistryClass theRegistry;
static void callingMethod(){
/// Some code here 
Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    char choice = in.next().charAt(0);

    if(choice == 1)
    {
       doAddStudent(aStudent);
    }

//remaining code here 

}
```

The method called in if block Declard in same class but outside of calling method

```
 private static void doAddStudent(Student aStudent) 
        {
            theRegistry.addStudent(aStudent); // static methods do not have reference to this
        }
```

if Caller Method is non Static
    TheRegistryClass theRegistry;
    void callingMethod(){
    /// Some code here 
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        char choice = in.next().charAt(0);

```
    if(choice == 1)
    {
       doAddStudent(aStudent);
    }

//remaining code here 

}



 private static void doAddStudent(Student aStudent) 
        {
            this.theRegistry.addStudent(aStudent); // this is optional
        }
```

Comment: when I type this out i get the error; "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: is `callingMethod` static in your code?   static methods do not get `this` reference. `the registry should be static too` updated answer.